# How do i create a tooltip using qTip2 that is assigned at run time to page elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip2

I'm trying to have a qTip2 bubble created but not displayed at load time. Then display it under any image clicked.

Please advise what is the best way to do this. (using qTip to solve the bubble going out of the screen).

Thanks

EDIT:

see problem with http://jsfiddle.net/jnbPP/5/ (looking for the correct way to do this)

Comment: you may need to use jquery live , i think they might have given that option somewhere...

Comment: Can you post some code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then you need to load it on click, e.g.:

```
$('img[title]').live('click', function(event) {
        $(this).qtip({
              overwrite: false,
              content: {           
                 text: $(this).attr('title') ,
              },
              position: {
                  my: 'top center', 
                  at: 'bottom center', 
                  adjust : {
                    screen : true
                  }
              },  
              show: {
                 event: event.type,
                 ready: true,
                 solo: true
              },
              hide: 'unfocus',
                style: {
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-light'
              }
           });
    });
```

Check out my fiddle: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jnbPP/3/)

Use

```
adjust : {
     screen : true
}
```

to keep the tooltip on screen.

**Here you go**. [CLICK](http://jsfiddle.net/jnbPP/9/)

```
$('img[title]').live('click', function(event) {
    var content = $('#settings').clone();
    $('input', content).val( $(this).width() );

    $(this).qtip({
      overwrite: false,
      content: {           
            text: content,
            title: {
                text: ' ',
               button: true
            }
         },
         position: {
             my: 'top center',  // Position my top left...
             at: 'bottom center', // at the bottom right of...
             viewport: $(window)
          },

      show: {
         event: event.type,
         ready: true,
         solo: true
      },
      hide: 'unfocus',
         style: {
               classes: 'ui-tooltip-ajax ui-tooltip-light'
         }
   });
});
```

Comment: Here's what i had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/jnbPP/5/ 
Try click on both image (first pass works) where it displays the size of the image. But on the second pass only the second image shows the tooltip. Please advise

Comment: thats because "text" needs html and not an object, try http://jsfiddle.net/jnbPP/6/

Comment: The size of the image is no longer displayed in the box with that change